# Jquery countdown timer fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I need to show a user some questions in a loop, and while displaying a question there needs to be displayed a countdown timer like this one:

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear');
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#start').click(function() {
    progress(5, 5, $('#progressBar'));
  });

});
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='start'>Start</button>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The problem is: If I activate the timer *(press the start button in the fiddle)* while it's already started and going down, it starts to do crazy things: going up and down. 
I guess this has to do with the recursive nature of `setTimeout()`.
How do I reinitialize the timer (progressBar function) each time anew?

Comment: So you want it just start from the top everytime you press the start button?

Comment: Yes. And I can't achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clear the timeout. Like this:

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear');
    if(timeleft > 0) {
    if (window.timer) {
      clearTimeout(window.timer)
    }
    window.timer = setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#start').click(function() {
    progress(5, 5, $('#progressBar'));
  });

});
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='start'>Start</button>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the timeout in a variable and clear it when you want to start over.

```js
var animating = null;
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000, 'linear');
    if(timeleft > 0) {
        clearTimeout(animating);
        animating = setTimeout(function() {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
        }, 1000);
    }
};

$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#start').click(function() {
    progress(5, 5, $('#progressBar'));
  });

});
```

```css
#progressBar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 22px;
  background-color: #0A5F44;
}

#progressBar div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CBEA00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='start'>Start</button>
<div id="progressBar">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works as well. Thanks! I guess I have to accept the solution that was posted earlier.